# How to randomly select a kivy button position

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have two screens on kivy and when I am on the second screen there are two buttons. I would like these buttons to have a random position between two predefined positions. For example if the button '1 ' at a positiopn '2 ' the button 2 will have a position '1 '.

I tried a lot of methods but none worked and the method with Listproperty seemed to me to be the best.
When I try this method I have this error:

```
BuilderException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 38:
...
     36:            id :1
     37:            text:' 1'
>>   38:            pos: root.manager.pos1
     39:            size_hint: .30, .10
     40:            background_color: 0,1,0,0.75
...
ValueError: Button.pos value length is immutable
  File "C:\src2\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 696, in _apply_rule
    setattr(widget_set, key, value)
  File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 35, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__setattr__
  File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 497, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
  File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 1356, in kivy.properties.ReferenceListProperty.set
  File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 1345, in kivy.properties.ReferenceListProperty.check
```

Thanks to whoever will take the time to help me

Sorry for my bad english

This is my code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import random
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, StringProperty
kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, BooleanProperty, NumericProperty
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

kv = """


MyScreenManager:
    MenuScreen:
        name: 'menu'
    Question1:
        name: "question1"

    


<MenuScreen>:
            
    FloatLayout:
        Button: 
            text:"Commencer"
            pos: 270, 300
            size_hint : .30, .10
            background_color: 0,1,0,0.75
            on_press: 
                root.manager.current: 'question1'
                root.update_pos()
    

<Question1>:
    
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            id:2
            text: '2'
            pos: root.manager.pos2
            size_hint: .30, .10
            background_color: 0,1,0,0.75
        Button:
            id :1
            text:' 1'
            pos: root.manager.pos1
            size_hint: .30, .10
            background_color: 0,1,0,0.75

            

            
"""

ab= 180 #hauteur des boutons
ac= 240 #hauteur des boutons
ae= 270 #abcisse des boutons

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pos1= ListProperty()
    pos2= ListProperty()

    


class MenuScreen(Screen): 
    
    def update_pos(self):
        d= [(ae,ab),(ae,ac)]
        random.shuffle(d)
        self.pos1= d[0]
        self.pos2= d[1]
        
    pass


class Question1(Screen):  
    pass 



class Quizz(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Quizz'
        Window.clearcolor = (0, 1, 1, 0.25)
        
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Quizz().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is due to your use of `ListProperty`. The default value of a `ListProperty` is `[]`, which when used in `pos: root.manager.pos2` is trying to change the length of `pos` to zero. So your code will work with a few minor changes. Change you class definitions:

```
class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pos1 = ListProperty([0,0])
    pos2 = ListProperty([0,0])


class MenuScreen(Screen):

    def update_pos(self):
        d = [(ae, ab), (ae, ac)]
        random.shuffle(d)
        self.manager.pos1 = d[0]
        self.manager.pos2 = d[1]
```

This changes the default of the `ListProperty` to `[0,0]`, just to get the length correct. The `update_pos()` method now changes the `pos1` and `pos2` in the `ScreenManager`, where the `ListProperties` are.

Then in the `kv` for `MenuScreen`:

```
<MenuScreen>:

    FloatLayout:
        Button: 
            text:"Commencer"
            pos: 270, 300
            size_hint : .30, .10
            background_color: 0,1,0,0.75
            on_press: 
                root.manager.current = 'question1'
                root.update_pos()
```

The only change here is to use `=` instead of `:` to assign the `current` screen name.